# Mysql - Copy row colum values from one table to another table (2 times) with different row values

Tags: mysql, rows, bulkinsert

I have been trying this query but its giving  me an error. I believe the query is right, but i 'm not getting the desired result as i wanted. Any inputs or guidance would be greatly appreciated. The following queries work only if i run the first query, but when i run the first and second query, it gives me error!

```
queries:
insert into user_tbl(firstname, lastname, location) 
select `fname`, `lname`, `location` from temp_tbl

insert into user_tbl(location) 
select `location2`from ok
```

If i run the first query, it copies from temp_tbl to user_tbl without any error

```
Only first query output!
--------------------------------
firstname, lastname, location
john       doe        New York
jane       doe        Mexico
```

This is my desired output:

```
user_tbl:
--------------------------------
firstname, lastname, location
john       doe        New York
                      Manhattan
jane       doe        Mexico
                      Bahamas
```

I don't know if there's any other query im missing here, but the query above is what i've come up with. So, basically what i want is whenever a single row columns values from **temp_table** table to **user_tbl** table is copied, i want a new row inserted for that same row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you need empty first/last names for 2nd/4th row from your desired output?

Comment: yes, thats right, i want an empty first, last name for the 2nd/4th rows. Also, i don't want to limit to 2nd/4th rows, if its possible i want to make it flexible so that the query can insert more than one empty rows for every row copied from tmp_tbl. Eg:- 2nd, 3rd / 5th, 6th rows / 2nd, 3rd, 4th / 6th, 7th, 8th rows .

Comment: ok, next question - what locations should be stored for each row with empty names? I mean in your example for 2nd you have Manhattan, but for 4th is Bahamas, how you will decide which location should go under which user?

Comment: Manhattan should go for the user 'john doe' and Bahamas  for the user 'jane doe', but there can be same names, so do i need to have some sort of unique_id column to map these empty rows to the container row ?

Comment: yes, you need something where you will store relation between user and locations, then you will be able to make proper query

Answer (score 0):

why would you insert a row with no first and last name?  I don't think you've architected correctly.  as far as reasons it failed, what is the error?  are the the first and lastname required fields maybe?

Comment: I have a requirement to upload multiple product items into the database. The format for the data is like the desired output i have given above.I also want to achieve insertion of two or more rows inside user_tbl for each row copied from temp_tbl.

Comment: well if you're coming from excel to a db, you're doing it wrong.  there is nothing linking the second insert to anything at all. also, the first query will affect the whole table, then the second will run, so the results are not interleaved.

Comment: ok, well i saw similar queries getting executed properly. But im getting this error:- check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into user_tbl(location) select `location` from temp_tbl' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

You should verify if the attributes "firstname" and "lastname" in the table user_tbl can accept null value. If these attributes are not null it is normal that you have an error when you try to insert only "location" in this table.